# Excel to datagridview Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0

Tags: excel, datagridview, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm trying to fill my datagrid view from an excel sheet. The error message I'm getting here is, oledb exception was ungandled --> `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.` I'm uisng office 2012, do i have to use any reference.

I put `anycpu`X86 in the project properties.

There are system files:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;



private void importXSLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();

            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test\csharp.net-informations.xls;ExtendedProperties=""Excel 14.0;HDR=YES;""";

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, TYPE, BeginBorder (mm),EndBorder (mm)," + "FROM [P2S2$]", connect);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];



        }
```

Comment: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0 ` is the Access Database driver. I believe you will have to add that as a reference.

Comment: @Pynner: I have added it to the reference, still it got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem with connectionString :

```
connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source=C:\test\csharp.net-informations.xls;ExtendedProperties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";
```

I have added the reference to the project and changed to any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS
connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source=C:\test\csharp.net-informations.xls;ExtendedProperties=Excel 12.0;";

IT SHOULD BE WORK
BEST REGARDS.